# BootstrapWP - setting a fixed width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

New to wordpress and web design in general. I'm trying to setup a website for my fathers business using the bootstrap wordpress ([boostrapwp](http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me)) theme. Having some trouble setting the themes width to a fixed width rather than the fluid width thats default.

Comment: I think the whole point of bootstrap is that it's flexible, also this question is more related to CSS than WordPress itself.

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This is a **CSS** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like the following.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

By default, this uses a 940px width. If you need to change that to make it more or less wide

Comment: @TeemuLeisti you can add css that loads after bootstrap that reads: `.container {
  width: 1200px;
}` for example.